# React: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'filterOpenStateI | Dispatch<SetStateAction<filterOpenStateI>>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a menu which has to have a state, so I can later track is it open or not. So I have decided to use Reacts useState() and for now I do have a problem that I cannot update the state like this in my JSX:

```
{filterOpenState[`${filterTab.id}`] == true ? <TiTimes /> :<BiDownArrowAlt />}
```

On this line I do get another error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

This is how I define state and interface:

```
 type filterOpenStateI = {
    [key: string]: boolean
  }    
const filterOpenState = useState<filterOpenStateI >({
        filterType: false,
        filterFlag: false,
        filterPriceRange: false,
      })
    
      const handleMenuState = (e: any)=>{
       e.preventDefault();
       const filterTabId = e.target.closest('div').id
       // Switch the value from state
       filterOpenState[filterTabId] = !filterOpenState[filterTabId]
      }
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this as I should `filterOpenStateI` was working when I defined `filterOpenState` without useState, but only a dict. But then after the dict changed, the react component did render the same thing, because I guess this didn't force react to re-render? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

filterOpenState is immutable, you are just allowed to modify it via func setState.
In your code, there are 2 mistakes

- useState returns an array in which 1st item is an object, and the 2nd is setState func.
- you are trying to reassign its value directly. It's the wrong way.

Comment: So how should I define useState? By reassigning its value I should use the setFilterOpenState?